# RedirectToAction and Routing not passing parameter correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use a RedirectToAction method after a selfposting Action (which passes IsValid). The redirect happens fine but the parameter I am attempted to pass to the action is always null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadForm(UploadFormViewModel formVM)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(formVM);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UploadConfirm", new { confirmVM = new UploadConfirmViewModel() });
}

public ActionResult UploadConfirm(UploadConfirmViewModel confirmVM)
{
        return View(confirmVM);
}
```

And here is my routing

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UploadConfirm",
            "{controller}/{action}/{confirmVM}",
            new { controller = "EnrollmentUpload", action = "UploadConfirm" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "EnrollmentUpload", action = "UploadForm", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `new{}` in your return statement:

```
return RedirectToAction("UploadConfirm", new UploadConfirmViewModel());
```

I also did not add an extra route to the Routecollection